# Exact category and splitting

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

How can i prove that if $C$ is an exact category and this short exact sequence
$0\to A \to B\to 0$ where $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ then $f$ is split mono iff $g$ is split epi.

I tried using the result that if $C$ is exact and the sequence is exact then $f$ is mono, $g$ is epi and $f$ is the kernel of $g$ but i don't know what else should i do

Comment: Your sequence is missing a term, and you have used the same letter $C$ for both the category and an object in that category.

Comment: If $f$ is a split mono, then there exists a map $r:B\to A$ such that $rf=1_A$. Now consider the endomorphism of $B$ given by $1_B-fr$. Can you show that this factors through $g$?